# Disable expect echoing password when using read -s

Tags: bash, tcl, expect

I have a bash script that asks for a password using "read -s". Running the script through expect echoes the password to the terminal. The strange thing is that it works as desired maybe 1 in 5 times, but most of the time it doesn't. Is there any reliable way to disable this?

#### Bash Script

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p 'login name? ' name
read -s -p 'password? ' pass
read -p $'\nfavorite color? ' color
echo -e "$name\n$pass\n$color"
```

#### Expect Script

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn -noecho ~/tmp/login_test
expect "login name? " {send "gordon\r"}
expect "password? " {
  #stty -echo     -- This doesn't work
  #log_user 0     -- This doesn't work either
  send "gr33d\r"
  #log_user 1
  #stty echo
}
expect "favorite color? " {send "green\r"}
expect eof {exit}
```

#### What I want

```
> ~/tmp/login_test
login name? gordon
password? 
favorite color? green
gordon
gr33d
green
```

#### What I usually get

```
> ~/tmp/expect_test
login name? gordon
password? gr33d

favorite color? green
gordon
gr33d
green
```

Comment: That's strange; it works for me _exactly as you want_ when I try it.

Comment: I updated my question- it seems to work as expected about 15% of the time. I think part of the problem is that "send" is an asynchronous command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! The solution is to sleep for 1ms...

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn -noecho ~/tmp/login_test
expect "login name? " {send "gordon\r"}
expect "password? " {sleep .001; send "gr33d\r"}
expect "favorite color? " {send "green\r"}
expect eof {exit}
```